# How to Click the textarea automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## HTML Code

```
<textarea id="id1">
 Contents inside
</textarea>
```

## Html 5

we can use **auto focus** for directly click the textarea. But i want to achieve without using autofocus. We may use Jquery and Js.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I don't know difference between focus and trigger event , guess it will provide the same functionality. But trigger is working for me in proper manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in the document's ready function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id1').focus();
});
```

jQuery's [`.focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) method focuses on an element programatically.

Comment: we should not use select and focus for achieving this , please suggest something else ?

Comment: Actually the problem is while calling the focus , it should look into the textarea, but it should not refresh the Textarea. It was huge and old project have to refresh the textarea while loading the page itself .Thats why i am asking this question.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand. Just giving a `.focus()` will refresh the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').focus();
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.